# Xamarin Apple Account error: There was an error while loading your certificates: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to solve [this problem that I have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69286865/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-deploying-app-f). Checking iOS configuration I realized that I have another problem with Apple Account certificates, I don't know if this problem is causing the first one. I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.11.3 ​on Windows 10 Pro laptop. At this moment the iPhone is running iOS 15 and the Macbook has Xcode 13 and xamarin.ios SDK 15.0.0.6 (downloaded from [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/12778)) installed.

In Visual Studio, I follow these steps:

- Go to Tools > Options > Xamarin > Apple Accounts.
- Select the team.
- Press the "View Details..." button.

I get this error while certificates and provisioning profiles are loading:

**There was an error while loading your certificates: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

[image: There was an error while loading your certificates: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

Then, the provisioning profiles are loaded successfully.

If I try to create a certificate pressing Create Certificate > iOS Development button, I get the same error.

All certificates are installed in the Macbook dragging files to Keychain.

Comment: I found a description of the error in this log file: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Logs\Xamarin.Messaging-16.11.000.175\<timestamp>.IDB.Local.log. The final line of the stack trace is this (for me):

at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.AppleProvisioningManager.<SyncSigningIdentitiesAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\3\s\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local\AppleProvisioningManager.cs:line 124